# Android set text width of the edittext? setTextSize is for height only, why?

Tags: android, text-size

I noticed that the `setTextSize(int)` modifies the height only of the characters of edittext. How can I specify the width of the characters of edittext. I cannot use `edittext.setwidth` because it only changes the width of the edittext and not the width of the characters. I need to format the text because I would like to insert a hint which has the same font size as the text.

If possible, I also do not have an initial text for the edittext to measure.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912565/how-to-set-edittext-width-to-one-character/16912591#16912591

Answer (score 0):

Change hint size and text size both by following code in your edit text in xml

```
android:textSize="14sp"
```

It will result in both hint size and text size of "14sp"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Check out : [android:textScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AtextScaleX)

Depending on how much spacing you need, this might help. That's the only thing remotely related to letter-spacing in the TextView.