# trying to make a text console with 40 columns or characters

Tags: android, kotlin, view, fonts, textview

I am extending a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and I have the font set to this font
[Unicode font](http://www.unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html)

here is the xml where I declare it

```
<jacs.apps.jacs.CustomViews.Console
        android:id="@+id/auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@id/content_frame"
        android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:fontFamily="@font/unifont"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:typeface="monospace"

        />
```

and here is my class

```
class Console : AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView {
    private var mCharHeight = 0
    private var h: Int = 0
    private var mIsSearchEnabled = true
    protected val heightVisible: Int
        get() {
            val rect = Rect()
            getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            return rect.bottom - rect.top
        }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

    private fun refitText(text: String, textWidth: Int) {
        val mTestPaint = Paint()
        mTestPaint.set(this.paint)
        if (textWidth <= 0)
            return
        val targetWidth = textWidth - this.paddingLeft - this.paddingRight
        var hi = 100f
        var lo = 2f
        val threshold = 0.5f // How close we have to be

        mTestPaint.set(this.paint)

        while (hi - lo > threshold) {
            val size = (hi + lo) / 2
            mTestPaint.textSize = size
            if (mTestPaint.measureText(text) >= targetWidth)
                hi = size // too big
            else
                lo = size // too small
        }
        // Use lo so that we undershoot rather than overshoot
        this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo)
        Log.d("baseline", "textsize: $textSize")

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val height = measuredHeight
        refitText("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", parentWidth)
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height)

    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        onDropDownChangeSize(w, h)
    }

    protected fun onDropDownChangeSize(w: Int, h: Int) {
        val rect = Rect()
        getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
        //Logger.debug(TAG, "onDropdownChangeSize: " + rect);
        // 1/2 width of screen
        dropDownWidth = (w * 0.5f).toInt()
        // 0.5 height of screen
        //setDropDownHeight((int) (h * 1f));
        dropDownHeight = 300
        this.h = h
        Log.d("suggestions", "h : $h")
        //change position
        onPopupChangePosition()
    }

    fun setSearchEnabledTrue() {
        mIsSearchEnabled = true
        setSearchEnabled(true)

    }

    fun setSearchEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean) {
        mIsSearchEnabled = isEnabled
    }

    override fun performFiltering(text: CharSequence, keyCode: Int) {
        if (mIsSearchEnabled) {
            super.performFiltering(text, keyCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
        val conn = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs)
        outAttrs.imeOptions = outAttrs.imeOptions and EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION.inv()
        return conn
    }

    override fun showDropDown() {
        if (mIsSearchEnabled) {
            onPopupChangePosition()

            super.showDropDown()
        }

    }

    protected fun invalidateCharHeight() {
        mCharHeight = Math.ceil(paint.fontSpacing.toDouble()).toInt()
        mCharHeight = paint.measureText("M").toInt()
    }

    protected fun onPopupChangePosition() {
        try {
            val layout = layout
            invalidateCharHeight()
            if (layout != null) {

                val pos = selectionStart
                val line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos)
                val baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line)
                val ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line)

                val bounds = Rect()
                val textPaint = paint
                val sample = "A"
                textPaint.getTextBounds(sample, 0, sample.length, bounds)
                val width = bounds.width() / sample.length


                val x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(pos)
                val y = (baseline + ascent).toFloat()

                val offsetHorizontal = x.toInt() + getWidth()
                dropDownHorizontalOffset = offsetHorizontal

                val heightVisible = heightVisible
                val offsetVertical = (y + mCharHeight - scrollY).toInt()

                val tmp = -h + offsetVertical + dropDownHeight + mCharHeight

                //if (tmp < heightVisible) {
                //tmp = -h + ((offsetVertical*2 / (mCharHeight)) * (mCharHeight / 2))+(mCharHeight/2);
                dropDownVerticalOffset = tmp
                Log.d("suggestions", "tmp : $tmp")
                //((Activity)(mContext)).setTitle("ov :"+offsetVertical +" ch "+mCharHeight+" tmp"+tmp +"h "+h+"p:"+pos);
                //                } else {
                //                    tmp = offsetVertical - getDropDownHeight() - mCharHeight;
                //                    setDropDownVerticalOffset(tmp);
                //                    ((Activity)(mContext)).setTitle(" 2 tmp :"+tmp);
                //                }


                //                int pos = getSelectionStart();
                //                int line = layout.getLineForOffset(pos);
                //                int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
                //                int ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line);
                //
                //                float x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(pos);
                //                float y = baseline + ascent;
                //
                //                int offsetHorizontal = (int) x + mGutterWidth;
                //                setDropDownHorizontalOffset(offsetHorizontal);
                //
                //                //    int heightVisible = getHeightVisible();
                //                int offsetVertical = (int) ((y + mCharHeight) - getScrollY());
                //
                //                int tmp = offsetVertical + getDropDownHeight() + mCharHeight;
                ////                if (tmp < heightVisible) {
                //                tmp = -(offsetVertical + mCharHeight) + ((offsetVertical / mCharHeight) * (mCharHeight / 2));
                //                setDropDownVerticalOffset(tmp);
                ////                } else {
                ////                    tmp = offsetVertical - getDropDownHeight() - mCharHeight;
                ////                    setDropDownVerticalOffset(tmp);
                ////                }

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    companion object {
        private val MINIMAL_HEIGHT = 100
    }

}
```

I am trying to make the view 40 characters wide for every device and it works on a bunch of different devices but when I run it on an emulator that's resolution is 720X1560 it lets 41 characters per row instead of the desired 40. I am trying to find a way to make the font size so that there are 40 characters per row.

**EDIT**
putting `android:paddingRight="35dp"` seemed to fix the problem although id like to know for sure also I cannot use newlines because I am already using them for a special kind of parsing

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `refitText` method as below:

```
private fun refitText(columns: Int, textWidth: Int) {
    val mTestPaint = Paint()
    mTestPaint.set(this.paint)
    if (textWidth <= 0)
        return
    val targetWidth = textWidth - this.paddingLeft - this.paddingRight
    val maxTextSize = 1000000f
    mTestPaint.textSize = maxTextSize
    val maxCharWidth = mTestPaint.measureText("m")
    var size = targetWidth * maxTextSize / (maxCharWidth * columns)
    do {
        mTestPaint.textSize = size
        val realCharWidth = mTestPaint.measureText("m")
        val requiredPadding = targetWidth - realCharWidth * columns;
        if (requiredPadding >= 0) {
            this.setPadding(this.paddingLeft + requiredPadding.toInt() / 2, this.paddingTop, this.paddingRight + requiredPadding.toInt() / 2, this.paddingBottom)
            break
        }
        size *= 1 - (Math.abs(requiredPadding) / targetWidth)
    } while (requiredPadding < 0)
    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size)

    Log.d("baseline", "textsize: $textSize")

}
```

Character width must be a positive integer of pixels because it's impossible to turn half of a pixel on and turn another half of that pixel off on the Display. 
Suppose you calculated a font size that renders 39 characters in your display with 720 pixels width. It means each character's width is 18 pixels (720/39=18). In other hand, to render 40 charachters, you have to reduce the font size. In this case, after reducing font size, the maximum character width could be 17 pixels. Now the first 39 characters will be shown on 663 pixels (39*17=663) and there are still 57 empty pixels (720-663=57) witch are enough to render 3 more characters (57/17=3) in that line. In this case, you need another limitation. So you should add some padding that are calculated dynamically to control number of characters in a line.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I tested it on a couple devices and it works fine. I gave you the bounty as I am just hoping that this will work on every device, thank you